# Is there any framework for bluetooth communication for iOS?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, bluetooth, core-bluetooth

I need a library or framework for bluetooth communication for iOS but not for Bluetooth LE.

I want to communicate a device that cast bluetooth package, but my device not support LE. I have iPhone 4, iPhone 4s and newer support Bluetooth LE.

for this iPhone 4s and newer version there ne problem lots of example I can find and also CoreBluetooth library support this.

So I want proper library or framework for this.

Any Idea or Suggestion would be highly welcome.

Comment: Gamekit framework is used to communicate between two iPhones.CoreBluetooth framework is used to two Bluetooth LE devices(Either two iPhones or iPhone to device)

Comment: Thank You Sir, but I want to connect device that is not BLE. And I want to connect iPhone 4 and lower to that not BLE device.

Comment: `ExternalAccessory.framework` for MFI compliant devices.

Answer (score 0):

Core Bluetooth is designed specifically for Bluetooth LE, a.k.a. BLE, Bluetooth 4.0 and Smart Bluetooth.

Core Bluetooth does not work with the older, classic Bluetooth devices. Those require special APIs and hardware available through Apple's MFi program. [Already answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12427718/ios-and-corebluetooth-low-energy-required)

Comment: Thank You Sir, but I want to connect device that is not BLE. And I want to connect iPhone 4 and lower to that not BLE device.